# Cell reference in Google Sheets Script

Tags: google-apps-script

From my question, you would know I am new to Google sheets script.
I am creating a macro to insert a cell below a specific string in a specific column. For example, I need insert a cell below a cell with value "Red". If the "Red" is in A5, then I need the cell A6, and A6 will be used multiple times in the macro. Any answers are appreciated!

All the best!

Comment: How to get A6? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
function findRed() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  let f = sh.createTextFinder('Red').findAll();
  let fA = f.map(r => { return {row: r.getRow(),col: r.getColumn()}} );
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(fA));
}

Execution log
11:12:41 AM Notice  Execution started
11:12:41 AM Info    [{"row":1,"col":1},{"row":4,"col":2},{"row":6,"col":4},{"row":8,"col":6},{"row":10,"col":8}]
11:12:42 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col5 | Col5 | Col6 | Col7 | Col8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Red |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | Red |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  | Red |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  | Red |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Red |

Comment: Hi, Cooper, I appreciate your quick response! All the best! Sean

Comment: Hello again, If only A1 is found, then I need write A2, or sometimes I may need write A2:G2, how to write it in script? I appreciate!

Comment: @AccountingAutomation  Better to ask follow up questions in a new post.

Comment: You can see that my code returns row and column for each item found if row,col = 1,1 then the one below it will always be at row +1 , column, or you can use sheet.getRange(row,col).offset(1,0);   and there are offset commands with more paramenters for expanding the range.  You will find them in Class Range.

Comment: Hi Cooper, I appreciate! Have a great day! Sean